# Importing worlds in Minecraft on Android: missing "games" folder

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've downloaded a world from the internet and now want to play it in Minecraft PE on Android. I've found tutorials online but they say I have to extract the world folder into a folder named "games" which I do not seem to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any worlds saved, delete them. Afterwards, an option will pop up to change where world are saved. Change that option to **external** and the folder will be created after restarting the app.

Answer (score 1):

After you download the app simply go into "settings" in the app you can enable "show hidden files" which will let you see the "games" folder and everything inside it.
Perhaps try downloading a different file manager app if you can't unhide your files.
I use the File Manager app so whatever app you use might not have the exact same procedure, though you can download and install worlds from from the app I use.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Profile -> File Storage Location

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you'll find there and how it works?

Comment: @ExperCoder14, Just toggle that setting to "external" and that's all (maybe after that you have to create an temporary world in order those folders appear, don't remember exactly)

Answer (score 0):

On Android, in your file manager, type in "Android". There will be a few (pic1) files named Android (I have 3), show me Android file and go into data where all your apps data is stored. If you will looking for a (pic2) data file with access denied "open with Google files" should be an option, then press it (pic3).
When you are in Google files, look for Android then data. In the data file look for com.mojang.minecraftpe and that's the folder.

[image: from left to right]